# os.path.getsize Invalid syntax error

Tags: python, latex

First thing first, code is list below,

```
import sys
import os
import latexmake

import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='oilwell',host='localhost',database='sqlpush1')

with conn:
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
mycursor=execute("SELECT DATE,oil,gas,oilprice,gasprice,totrev FROM results WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2027-12-01'")
rows = mycursor.fetchall()
a.write("\\documentclass{standalone}\\usepackage{booktabs}\n\n\\usepackage{siunitx}\r \n\
\r\n\\begin{document}\r\n\\begin{tabular}{ccS[table-format = 5.2]} \\\\ \\toprule\r")
a.write("Date & Oil & Gas & Oil price & Gas price & Total Revenue \\\\ \\midrule \r")
for row in rows:
    a = open("testtest.tex", "w")
    a.write("" + str(row[0]) + " & " + str(row[1]) + " & " + str(row[2]) + " & " + str(row[3]) + " & " + str(row[4]) + " & " + str(row[5]) + " \\\\ \r")

    a.write("\\bottomrule \\end{tabular}\r\\end{document}")
    a.close
print os.path.getsize("testtest.tex")
os.system('latexmk.py -q testtest.tex')
mycursor.close()
conn.close()
```

after run IDLE, an error called "Invalid Syntax" pop up on line "os.path.getsize"

I did import os at very beginning, and I don't know why.

Appreciated your kind help.

Regards,

Cheng

Comment: You don't close your file either `a.close -> a.close()`, you  open a after trying to  use it, open it once outside the loop  using `with`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the `os.path.getsize` that's the problem, it's the `print`. You're using Python 3 and `print` is now a function, and therefore needs parentheses.

```
print(os.path.getsize("testtest.tex"))
```

Also, it'd be nice (though admittedly, you'd never notice in this script) if you actually called `close` rather than just referencing it:

```
a.close()
```

Comment: The OP also try to use a before the create it

Comment: @kindall, you are right, and that's a lesson! nothing like this will happen in 2.7. However, after I changed it ,new error coming out.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cheng\Desktop\tabletest.py", line 8, in <module>
    with conn:
AttributeError: __exit__